# What's the plan for JFrog Xray 3.0?

Tags: continuous-integration, release, analysis, jfrog-xray

I see a lot of references to a mythical version 3.0 but did not find any information on when and what that should be, neither on the jfrog web site, wiki, nor out in the wild.

Are there any more concrete infos available?

Answer (score 1):

It  has been a while since it is released and the big changes is that it  came out as a Unified Platform where all products of JFrog are unified into one common UI with a unified installation and configuration. More details [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Get+Started)

Hope this helps.